# How to programaticly change a CUPS print job username

Tags: linux, printing, cups

Due to a messy user namespace situation at our site, we have a need to change the username associated with a submitted print job (job-originating-user-name) programmatically. For example, if user “bob” submits a job, it needs to be changed to user “robert” before being sent on to the next hop.

We’re running an old LPRng setup currently. It had a mechanism for “control filter” that will modify the contents of the LPD control file (cf). I’m looking for similar functionality in CUPS.

I’ve found the CUPS filter API document Filter and Backend Programming (cups.org)  All functions listed there are intended for dealing with printer interaction (not unusual as most filters are either changing file formats or interacting with the printer).

The CUPS programming manual https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html does have cupsSetUser() and cupsUser() functions…but this looks like it is referencing the user under which the filter is executed and not changing the user on the job in question.

Does CUPS have such capabilities? It looks like support was added to define a CUPS_USER variable in the user's shell environment to alter the user presented at the time the job is submitted...but we would prefer to determine the new username as part of a print filter rather than setting a shell environment variable.